# XmlStreamException - Got character[0] expected a valid XML character

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, apache-axis, axiom

I am seeing a strange behavior in invoking a webservice. I get the response successfully after this line is executed-

```
 OMElement result = client.sendReceive(payload);
```

Now if I hover the mouse and inspect the result which is an OMElement, then everything goes good and the following code executes successfully -

```
System.out.println(result.toString);
```

However if don't inspect the OMElement result variable, I get the following exception -

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at line:2 col:4000  Got character[0] expected a valid XML character
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:206)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.BEAStreamReaderWrapper.next(BEAStreamReaderWrapper.java:80)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:668)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:709)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:69)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:846)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:556)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:846)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:556)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:846)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:556)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:846)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:957)
    at com.thehartford.pi.opc.serviceproxy.policyinquiry.impl.PolicyInquiryServiceProxyImpl.parseResponse(PolicyInquiryServiceProxyImpl.java:134)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: Error at line:2 col:4000  Got character[0] expected a valid XML character
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.ScannerState.checkedRead(ScannerState.java:628)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.CharData.read(CharData.java:65)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.startState(Scanner.java:296)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:178)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.accept(BaseParser.java:533)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.accept(BaseParser.java:510)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.EndElement.parse(EndElement.java:34)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseElement(BaseParser.java:457)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseSome(BaseParser.java:326)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:195)
```

Could some one give me some lead on where the problem could be?

Comment: Can you post the code between the call to sendReceive and the call to toString?

Comment: There is no code in between. It is the next line.

Comment: Which Axiom version do you use?

Comment: axis2 1.6.2 & Axiom 1.2.13